# 'pod init' for 'pod lib create ...' created pod?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

Is doing a `pod init` inside a directory created via `pod lib create projectName` a supported scenario? It doesn't seem to have worked for me but otherwise how would one specify upstream dependencies of the pod they're in the process of creating?

`pod install` issues a few warnings about automatically assuming an ios version for each target but otherwise seems to succeed. But when I look for the files that it should have installed for pod 'Upsurge' (which is specified in my Podfile), they are no where to be found.

I tried adding `workspace 'projectName'` to my Podfile per the docs but it would be miraculous if that were enough for it to find my xcworkspace located in: `Example/projectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace` or `Example/projectName.xcworkspace` (which are the only two xcworkspaces in my entire tree) so I had little hope that that would actually work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was in the error which it spit out that I previously had considered ignorable:

`[!] Unable to integrate the following embedded targets with their respective host targets (a host target is a "parent" target which embeds a "child" target like a framework or extension):`

- `Pods-projectName_Tests (false) and Pods-projectName_Example (true) do not both set use_frameworks!.`

Once I set these to both true it downloaded some packages.

It is worth noting that the mismatched false and true values for `use_frameworks!` were actually initially emitted by `pod init` itself.